# How can i get group count by sql with group by keywords?

Tags: mysql, sql

Everyone,

I have a sql which retrieve all date group by postid as below:

```
Select * from table group by postid;
```

but i need to count the total group. below doesn't work for me, it list count for each group!but i need total group number!

```
Select count(*) from table group by postid;
```

How can i get all row number for this sql? (Select * from table group by postid;)

Thanks!

Comment: add the table Name "table" as 'table' or [table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT postid) FROM `table`
```